# Reading .NET BitmapData vertically (left to right) instead of top to bottom

Tags: c#, .net, bitmapdata

I am doing some work manipulating bitmaps in C#, and I am using `BitmapData` and a `byte` pointer to make it as quick as possible. The code below finds the first horizontal line of pixels vertically that has visible data in it (i.e. alpha value == !0) when reading top to bottom:

```
var rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 590, 590);
BitmapData data = logo.LockBits(rectangle, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, logo.PixelFormat);

var bmpBytes = (byte*)data.Scan0;
int nOffset = data.Stride - logo.Width * 4;

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        if (bmpBytes[3] > 0)
        {
            bmpBytes -= (y * x);
            return y;
        }
        bmpBytes += 4;
    }

    bmpBytes += nOffset;
}

return -1;
```

I now want to do the same thing, but read the data left to right and get the first vertical line of pixels that has visible data in it. The thing is with the bitmap data being 'flattenned' and placed in a row, if you will, I'm not sure how to do this.

Anyone any insight as to how I could do this?

Comment: Use `bmpBytes[x + y * data.Stride]` to index pixel bytes instead of incrementing bmpBytes.  Returning without calling Unlock is a bug btw.

Comment: do something similar to Hans Passant (multiply x by 4), and exchange your loops (first loop through x)

Comment: @HansPassant cheers for that I'll try it out later and update with my solution - and the code above isn't the exact code I am using, I just mashed a bit together to give a picture of what I was doing, in my real code I am unlocking the bits.